Trying to export baked cloth simulation messes up the geometry
I am working on a project that requires cloth simulation, as the animation from the baked cloth simulation is smoother than just apply a Shape Key to it I'm looking to keep that simulation, but as soon as I export it the geometry breaks up in random spiky patterns, I leave you guy a Screenshot:
Expected render:

Actual render:

I will be attentive to any comments, greetings

To me it looks somewhat like motion blur in the lower image, but since I don't know what the motion of this object is I could not verify it. And obviously you found a solution so it does not matter anyway. I was just wondering because the lower screenshot does not look like something I have ever seen being caused by a Subdivision Surface modifier (at least not without any motion blur involved).

Find the answer 10 seconds after posting this question.
All four objects had Subdivision Surface modifier applied, as I don't really need those modifiers i just delete them and problem solved.
